# ib_insync, extraction of all options

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, tws

I need to extract all options from interactive brokers for a particular underlying. For example, I need all options with expiration date in the next 3 months for `ADS` underlying. I am using `ib_insync` wrapper to extract the necessary information like `bid` and `ask`, etc. It works well, but I need the list of available options.

Thus, I need something like (i.e., pseudo-code below):

```
contracts = []
for underlying in ["ADS", "VOW"]:
   tmp = **give me a list of all options (i.e., strikes, expiration date) for *underlying***
   contracts.append(tmp)
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question when searching for the answer myself. I found the answer in the `ib_insync` documentation [here](https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=reqSecDefOptParams#ib_insync.ib.IB.reqSecDefOptParams).

```
spx = Index('SPX', 'CBOE')
chains = ib.reqSecDefOptParams(spx.symbol, '', spx.secType, spx.conId)
```